# Door label template

Tags: templates

Is there a LaTeX template for office door labels? I would like it to print several names (currently two, ideally configurable) in the form of a table, with office hours next to each one, in nice big font, to be printed on a full sized (a4) paper.

I used to have a custom one, but for now I've lost access to it due to a renovation, and anyway it was not so nice, and I can't seem to find anything like that that I would like on the web.

Comment: I'm not a door expert but why not simply a `\begin{tabular}{cc} .... \end{tabular}` then?

Comment: You can contact a template services and pay 400 Dollars for a very customizable template, you cange everything, fonts, placement, you name it. Or you can spend ten minutes of time and code the stuff up yourself using basic font an formatting commands. You decide. Nobody can give you a *perfect door label template* here.

Comment: @Johannes_B: There is no need to be patronizing. Why would nobody be able to give me a perfect door label template here? There are (kind of) perfect (free) templates for lots of things. I'm not asking people to do that for me specifically, just whether there is some kind of package/resource like this available.

Comment: @percusse: I think I did something like that the last time around, but then I had some problems with the font size (when I made the font big enough to be readable, the spacing between letters was too small), so I was wondering if there is some ready-made solution with pretty results I have not found.

Answer (score 4):

Since you gave no clue of what format, font you wanted, here is something for you to start with:

The `\employee` command scales the name to cover the whole text width. To go on adding more names just follow the lead. Font choosing is of your picking, there is the nice [Latex Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/) or you can use Lua/XeLaTeX with `fontspec` and pick any system font (including from other softwares).

Since this method scales each name to fit the page they will have different font sizes. To have all names with the same font size you can use instead of the `\employee` a tabular with one Employees Names column and another Working Hours column and the same scaling method to make it always fit the page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=5mm,paperwidth=297mm,paperheight=210mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{LobsterTwo}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand{\employee}[1]{\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{#1}\par}
\begin{document}
\centering
\vspace*{\fill}
\employee{John Doe, 8h to 18h}
\vspace{.1\textheight}
\hrule
\vspace{.1\textheight}
\employee{Aline Moraes, 12h --- 20h}
\vfill
\end{document}
```

[image]